# Django Project Logic Solution

Tags: python, sql, django, user-experience

I'm starting to develop my first webapp, and I'm using django.

Before anything I'm working on the software logic, how it should work, the links and objects it needs.

The problem is:

I need the app to create a new database for each new client(superuser) of mine. And this db should record some models containing info about some "read only" users, created by the admin.

The thing is, one "read only" user can, and possibly will be, in other databases from other superusers. Is it even possible to get access to the info of this "read only" user from one database to the other?

Or should I just use one database that handles multiple clients?

The superusers should NOT be related and they don't need to know about each other. The only thing that's important is that the "read only" users should get access to their data stored both superusers X and Y. This is every time they login the system.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put it all into one database. SuperUsers should only link to ReadOnly users data, so that the ReadOnly user data is not duplicated.

Comment: The data can't be duplicated, the info SuperUser X has about ReadOnly Z will always be different from the info SuperUser Y has about ReadOnly Z. But one db is probably the way to go, right?

Comment: I don't know Django. If you can set it up so that all read only user data is in a 'readonlyuserdata' entity that he himself can see completely, *and* you can limit which parts of 'readonlyuserdata' can be seen by the different superusers, then you have a good setup.